# xcode and ios and Global variables

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6

Is there a concept of global variables ? Like I want to check if I have a network or not initially and according show some functionality. I understand, I can keep passing the variable from form to form. Is that the only way

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical Objective C OOP coding solution here is to use the MVC pattern.  Instantiate these variables in a Model object, perhaps a singleton and/or pass that Model object down to the objects that need to get/set this state information.

But Objective C is also a superset of plain ANSI C.  So you can just use standard C global variables, accessible from anywhere in Objective C, if you don't need/want encapsulation for reusability/maintainability.

Comment: Thanks. I am assuming putting a variable in main will do the trick something like char *myvariable = "Initialized"; Let me try it.